# pip will not install to correct directory after virtualenv activated

Tags: python, macos, pip, virtualenv

I am running OSX 10.11.6, and like many people have the issue of not being authorized to install python packages globally. In the past, virtualenv seemed to solve this problem for me, but currently, after activating a virtual environment, when I run `pip install pandas`
I get this error:

`PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/__pycache__'`

It appears that even though I have activated a virtual environment, it is still trying to install the package globally. I have also tried `pip install --user pandas` but then I get the error:

`DistutilsOptionError: can't combine user with prefix, exec_prefix/home, or install_(plat)base`

Using `pip install --user --install-option="prefix=" pandas` results in the same error above.

I installed Python using homebrew, and for some reason a year ago roughly, virtual environments allowed me to install packages with not trouble. Does anyone have insight into why this is suddenly causing a problem?

Comment: I've never used the --user option...  what happens if you omit that option?  In other words, activate your venv then: pip install pandas

Comment: I have tried that, pip install pandas results in the first error; it prints to the global directory for Python packages rather than the one of the venv, even though I've activated the venv.

Comment: have you tried updating pip?  One of these two commands should do it. sudo -H pip install -U pip   or   sudo -H pip install -U pip  You can check which version you have by typing: pip --version